# VSCode won't work with filewatchers

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-sass

I am running this command to watch .scss files `node-sass-chokidar ./scss -o ./build --watch`

If I edit the file in notepad++ everything works fine and file compiles.

If I edit it in VSCode then after I save it gives this error:

```
{
  "status": 3,
  "message": "File to read not found or unreadable: E:/Clients/conversions/css/scss/mobile.scss",
  "formatted": "Internal Error: File to read not found or unreadable: E:/Clients/conversions/css/scss/mobile.scss\n"
}
```

I found some threads saying this is caused by atomic save but VSCode developer says in github thread that VSCode does not use atomic save.  But then in another thread he says it renames files so I guess this could be issue.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this and just make it save normally?

Answer (score 4):

remove -w flag and then compile it once, then put the -w back it will work now

Answer (score 2):

## Updated answer

I've created a patch for the node-sass watch bug when running on vscode.
It's available here: https://github.com/marcosbozzani/patch-node-sass-watch

How to use:

1. Create a folder named `patches` in your project
2. Download the [patch](https://github.com/marcosbozzani/patch-node-sass-watch/patches/node-sass+4.14.1.patch) to your project `patches` folder
3. Install [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

Another option is to change from `node-sass` to `dart-sass`:

```sh
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

and update the command from

```sh
node-sass scss/ -o .build/ --watch
```

to

```sh
node-sass scss/:build/ --watch
```

---

## Original answer

I had the same problem. So I've created a patch for it and submitted a pull request to node-sass: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/pull/2386

The problem seems to be VSCode is still holding the file while node-sass try to access it. This fix detects this case and apply a retry mechanism.

If you want to try it now, as a temporary measure, you can patch your node-sass local copy by replacing 'node_modules/node-sass/lib/render.js' with this version: https://github.com/marcosbozzani/node-sass/blob/bug-vscode-watch/lib/render.js

The diff is here: https://github.com/marcosbozzani/node-sass/commit/266861bf5761dcafd5d53d123264b965c861887c#diff-a485abf5b8f49de7f313d7799df3faf4

Comment: ```node-sass scss/:build/ --watch```  must be changed to ```sass scss/:build/ --watch``` Because you are installing sass (node-sass is deprecated) you must make that change to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a node-sass as the compiler and vscode or sublime text AFAIK, the issue is with atomic save option where node-sass can't have access to transpile the scss file because the editor is still busy with it. Two ways of fixing this include:

1. Replace render.js file of `node-sass`

check [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1894#issuecomment-390199128)
there is a drawback of having to do this everytime you install node-sass

2. Install `sass` module instead

   $ yarn add -D sass

script

```
$ sass --watch input.scss output.css
```

check [here](https://sass-lang.com/guide) for more on sass

Answer (score 0):

When I experienced that I hit save 3-4 times, got errors like that the first few times but eventually it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here, using "node-sass": "5.0.0" I was facing this issue too.

For me, the solution was change the script command:

```
node-sass sass/file.scss css/filecompiled.css --w
```

**to**

```
sass sass/file.scss css/filecompiled.css --watch
```

and now, everything is running perfectly.

```
"Compiled sass\file.scss to css\filecompiled.css."
```

Comment: it should be -w or --watch.  I think issue is you used two hypens with w